# Reading SPI gyro values from IIM-42652

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, spi, gyroscope, imu

Has anyone on here ever used a IIM-42652 before? I am trying to communicate to it but have trouble reading gyroscope values.
I have verified all the SPI signals on both MISO and MOSI lines, alongside all specified SPI communication and timing parameters using an oscilloscope.
As a result, I am capable of reading values for the accelerometer. However, I keep getting 0x80 on the upper byte of the gyro and 0x00 on the lower byte of the gyro (X-axis), which means its an invalid reading.

datasheet - https://invensense.tdk.com/download-pdf/iim-42652-datasheet/

Comment: When asking questions like this please make sure to include a link to the datasheet.

Comment: sorry, my bad. here it is
https://invensense.tdk.com/download-pdf/iim-42652-datasheet/

Comment: If you get accelerometer readings, but not gyro, sounds like a device configuration issue.  From a quick scan of the datasheet, I probably check GYRO_MODE and GYRO_CONFIG registers first.  Maybe check the app note "AN-000173" too, and if working for a large enough company to get support reach out to your TDK Field application engineer.

Answer (score 0):

There are endless ways that will stop proper acc and/or gyro convertion in the IMU. As @Brian McFarland stated the Config and Mode registers could be the issue but almost any other. I had issues with accelorometer data and it was due to missconfigured fifo registers. Just forgot to "OR" the register settings with the default value that were in there -_-